# Reverse for 'yourchoice' not found. 'yourchoice' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I'm very new. I've created an application on a webproject with django. I'm facing the following error

```
Reverse for 'yourchoice' not found. 'yourchoice' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

But I have the function in the views.py. This is the part of views.py

```
def yourchoice(request, courseId):
    course = get_object_or_404(AllCourses, pk=courseId)
    try:
        selected_ct = course.details_set.get(pk=request.post('[choice]'))
    except (KeyError, AllCourses.DoesNotExist):
        raise render(request, 'technicalCourse/details.html', {
            'choice': choice,
            'error': 'Enter a valid option'
        })
    else:
        selected_ct.choice = True
        selected_ct.save()
        return render(request, 'technicalCourse/details.html', {'courseObj': course})
```

This is the part of html.I'm getting error in the form tag.

```
<form action="{% url 'technicalCourse:yourchoice' courseId.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in courseObj.details_set.all %}
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{courseId}}">
<label for="choice{{forloop.counter}}">{{ choice.ct }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I've also added this in the urls.py with necessary imports

```
app_name="technicalCourse"

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:courseId>/',views.details,name='details_page'),
    path('', views.course,name='Home_page'),
    path('<int:courseId>/yourchoice/', views.yourchoice,name='your_choice'),
]
```

How to resolve this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The name of your url is `your_choice` not `yourchoice`. Use:

```
{% url 'technicalCourse:your_choice' courseId=courseId.id %}
```

I also changed it to use a named argument rather than positional.

Comment: schillingt thank you , now its working I misunderstood that it should be the function name.
My admin page css is not working , can you give me some suggestion for that?

Comment: @KrispieeKesavan _My admin page css is not working , can you give me some suggestion for that?_ That sounds like a different issue entirely.

Comment: @AMC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120606/django-admin-page-and-css this the issue I'm facing since I started django few weeks back.I try a lot but couldn't figure it out

Comment: That's unrelated to this question.

Comment: how to pass two variables like courseid _1, courseid_2