# Css not loading in Django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

My css file is not getting loaded in the webpage. I have css and image file in the same location. The image is getting loaded but not the css.Also I have included the directory in staticfile_dirs. 
Setting.py

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'technicalCourse.apps.TechnicalcourseConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            r'C:\Users\Kesavan\PycharmProjects\Django web development\website\technicalCourse\template'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    r'website\technicalCourse\static',
]
```

This the template file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/simple.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<img src="{% static 'image/img.png' %}">
<h1>Welcome to course on programming</h1>
<ol>
    {% for x in ac %}
    <li><a href="{{x.id}}/">{{x.courseName}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
</body>
```

For testing I simply change the color of the h1 tag alone. The css file.

```
h1{
color:black;
}
```

Structure

```
C:.
├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   ├───css
│   └───image
├───template
│   └───technicalCourse
└───__pycache__
```

But there is no reflection on the webpage.
Hoping for the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the css file in the same directory as the image? if yes, why do you load the css file from `css/simple.css` and the image from `image/img.png`?

Comment: I have css in css folder and image in img folder. both of these folders are under same folder. image is loading but css is not.

Comment: I have updated the folder structure now.

Comment: what do you mean by `I have css in css folder and image in img folder`? Do you simply mean both files are in the same `static` dir or do you have folders called `css` and `image` inside the static folder. Your folder hierarchy contradicts your comment above.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 I have folder named css and image inside static folder,I've posted the file structure also

Comment: And the solution below doesnt work?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 u mean python manage.py collectstatic, No.

Comment: `color:black;` is the default so you don't really see any changes. Try `color:red;` and see if it applies the change.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 tried , it's not working. I have problem with admin page css too. From the moment I installed django my admin page is always without css. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120606/django-admin-page-and-css/61290381#61290381 this is thee issue I'm facing till now.

Comment: See my answer, it will solve the problem but not in a djangonic way.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution. I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

try this command:

```sh
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and check again.

Comment: This only helps with live server environment. It would be of no use when you start it normally.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that `images` are working and `CSS` isn't. There could be a multitude of possibilities for your problem.

The simplest way to solve this is to set the path to the `CSS` files via an `absolute` or a `relative` path.

Relavtive path case

```
<link href="/static/ui/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I tried this before, even with full path like C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Django web development\website\technicalCourse\static\css. Still facing the same issue

Comment: last possible solution:Try add `/` to your link tag end, e.g.

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yee.css"/>

Comment: @KrispieeKesavan Did that work? If not then, only an expert can help

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering with same problem but solved by adding the

```
{% load static %}
    {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'thumbnail_searcher/style.css' %}">
    }
```

in same tag. For example in your case add `load` and `link` into `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. **clear** browser cache
2. in settings.py **change** STATIC_URL = "static/" **to** STATIC_URL = "/static/"
3. **run** python manage.py runserver port_number(optional)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

$ python manage.py findstatic **css/style.css**

instead of **css/style.css** add your own path

If Django project able to locate the CSS, it will return **path** to your CSS file.

**Then restart** your project and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue..in my case i had not setup the STATICFILES_DIRS path in my settings.py.
try changing `STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), r'website\technicalCourse\static', ]`
to `STATICFILES_DIRS=( os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'), )`
this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similiar problem. My css wasn't loading. I troubleshootet it about an hour and it just didn't work. I renamed my css file and now it was working. Some really weird bug, but it worked for me.

Comment: what was the name before and after?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).